# Magento update custom option image on cart page

Tags: custom-options, image-upload

Is there any way to allow user that user can edit on cart page item and reupload the uploaded custom option image from cart page itself.
So there is no need to go to product detail page from cart item.

Comment: what is version of magento?

Comment: Magento 1.9 version